# asyncio in django view

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-asyncio

2018-05-30 09:53:21 [exception ERROR] Internal Server Error: /of/template/team
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wangchao/.virtualenvs/ENV_PY3.6_zbxtree/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 155, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/wangchao/Documents/SenseTime/sencetime_git/wangchao3/zabbixbiztree/biztree/of/views/template_team.py", line 33, in get_context_data
    self.test()
  File "/Users/wangchao/Documents/SenseTime/sencetime_git/wangchao3/zabbixbiztree/biztree/of/views/template_team.py", line 29, in test
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 596, in gather
    fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 518, in ensure_future
    loop = events.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 676, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 584, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
2018-05-30 09:53:21 [basehttp ERROR] "GET /of/template/team HTTP/1.1" 500 118472

```
class TemplateTeamView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):

    template_name = 'of/template_team.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = [of._get_detail_template(i) for i in [1,2,3,4]]
        result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
        context = super(TemplateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({"result": result})
        return context
```

how to design calling multi APIs to gather result before render template?

Comment: Do you have the complete traceback from the error? Feels like this is missing the actual exception.

Comment: i know maybe celery can fix it.  but i am thinking to use multi-threadings or coroutine to get APIs result before template rendered.

Comment: You will not really benefit from using asyncio within Django, because Django isn't an async framework. Even if you were to make your code run, you wouldn't be able to serve more requests from that Django process, vs. if you are using aiohttp or tornado.

Comment: so can you please give me any better suggestion here?  you see i need some API results before template rendered. thanks a lot

Comment: i found the key of the exception.  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() --> loop = asyncio.new_event_loop(); asyncio.set_event_loop(loop).  but still as you said, it won't be able to serve more requests